# How to create table using elixir reporting tool?

Tags: report, reporting

How to share experience on working with elixir reporting tool?

I need to create a table with dynamic columns from db. How to create a table with dynamic columns using elixir reporting tool?

```
sql:select id,name from customer where dept_id='1442';
```

Above query return set of records. I need to pass that records dynamically to a table using elixir reporting tool.

The tool description can find below

http://www.elixirtech.com/

Comment: Are you sure this is tagged correctly? See the stackoverflow elixir tag [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/elixir/info)

Comment: thanks for reply your question is correct. i am using a tool name called elixir,but in tags only elixir programming language is there